# Combining two for loops to improve efficiency

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am making a bunch of graphs by looping through csv files,and then making multiple graphs based on a groupby. The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd   
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages


frame=pd.read_csv('C:\\')

pdf_files = {}
for group_name, group in frame.groupby(['Allotment','Year','Month','Day']):
    allotment,year,month,day = group_name
    if month not in pdf_files:
        pdf_files[allotment,month] = PdfPages(r'F:\Sheyenne\Statistics\IDL_stats\Allotment_histos\Month\SWIR32' + '_' + allotment + '_'+ month + '.pdf') 
    plot=group.plot(x='Percent', y='SWIR32', title=str(group_name)).get_figure()
    pdf_files[allotment,month].savefig(plot)
    plt.close(plot)

for key in pdf_files:
    pdf_files[key].close()

print "Done"
```

but this is returning an error saying there are too many open files.  I think if I can combine the two for loops into one this may get around this problem, but I am unsure of how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you can't groupby `['allotment', 'month']` first then each loop would just be a single pdf file (and probably better to use `with PdfPages(...) as pdf_file:`)

```
basename = r'F:\Sheyenne\Statistics\IDL_stats\Allotment_histos\Month\SWIR32'
for file_name, file in frame.groupby(['Allotment','Month']):
    allotment, month = file_name
    with PdfPages('{}_{}_{}.pdf'.format(basename, allotment, month)) as pdf_file:
        for group_name, group in file.groupby(['Allotment','Month','Year', 'Day']):
            plot = group.plot(x='Percent', y='SWIR32', title=str(group_name)).get_figure()
            pdf_file.savefig(plot)
            plt.close(plot)
```

Comment: `with PdfPages('{}_{}_{}.pdf'.format(basename, allotment, month) as pdf_file:` returns a syntax error

Comment: Sorry missing paren - fixed

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
import pandas as pd   
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

frame=pd.read_csv('C:\\')

pdf_files = {}
for group_name, group in frame.groupby(['Allotment','Year','Month','Day']):
    allotment,year,month,day = group_name
    if month not in pdf_files:
        pdf_files[allotment,month] = PdfPages(r'F:\Sheyenne\Statistics\IDL_stats\Allotment_histos\Month\SWIR32' + '_' + allotment + '_'+ month + '.pdf') 
    plot=group.plot(x='Percent', y='SWIR32', title=str(group_name)).get_figure()
    pdf_files[allotment,month].savefig(plot)
    pdf_files[allotment,month].close()
    plt.close(plot)

print "Done"
```

Basically just make sure you close the file after you're done editing it.

Comment: As written, that won't work because it will sometimes access a file that has been closed. I would simplify it and just not try to cache the file objects at all. Just open a file each time and close it when done. If that's too slow, I would cache the output plots in memory and then just write to the files at the very end. I would avoid the middle ground of having many open file objects.

Comment: Ahh, you're completely right Luke.  It makes sense to break down the logic that way anyway.